# How to get a partial rounded border with border-radius using CSS?

Tags: html, css, border, linear-gradients

I have seen solutions using pseudo elements, `border-image` and gradient background, which achieve getting a partial border. But none of them seem to work for getting a partial border which respects the `border-radius` property.

I want to achieve something like this -

[image]

The closest I could get was using this -

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(#374FDE,#374FDE) top left/ 20px 2px no-repeat, linear-gradient(#374FDE,#374FDE) left top/ 2px 20px no-repeat, #CDD8FF;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

But as you can see, it still clips the borders at the corners. Is there any way in HTML + CSS that I can achieve this (without using an SVG element)? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple background and background-clip can achieve this. The trick is to have a transparent border that you color with a partial gradient then another gradient to color the padding area:

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    background: 
       linear-gradient(#CDD8FF,#CDD8FF) padding-box,
       linear-gradient(#374FDE,#374FDE) top left/20px 20px border-box;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border:2px solid transparent;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Like below too:

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    background: 
       linear-gradient(#CDD8FF,#CDD8FF) padding-box,
       linear-gradient(135deg,#374FDE 20px,#CDD8FF 0)  border-box;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border:2px solid transparent;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Another syntax:

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    background: 
       linear-gradient(#CDD8FF,#CDD8FF) padding-box,
       linear-gradient(to right, #374FDE 20px,#CDD8FF 0) 0 0/100% 20px  border-box,
       linear-gradient(#CDD8FF,#CDD8FF) border-box;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border:2px solid transparent;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

You can also consider a pseudo element that you cut with a clip-path or mask:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #CDD8FF;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 2px solid #374FDE;
  clip-path:inset(0 calc(100% - 30px) calc(100% - 20px) 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

.

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#div1 {
    position:relative;
    margin:20px auto;
    width:20%;
    padding-bottom:20%;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
}
#div1:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-1px; left:-1px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

resourse : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/y3EfP/147/

Comment: As the question describes, it should be a partial border which is rounded at the corners. Yours is no way near that

Comment: watching your code sample .. it looked like you aren't able to get curved borders

Comment: Curved borders, but partial as well

Comment: Yes, that would work if you wanted for all corners, but not as needed in one corner.